# Getting error "No such file or directory"

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I'm trying to test my created script to learn more about scripting and encountered the error "No such file or directory" despite that my .sh script is on the same folder of my .sql file. By the way, I'm using gitbash to run my .sh script.

[image]

This is just my script:

```
SQL_FILE = ./test.sql

echo "test test test"
echo "SELECT * FROM testDb;" > "${SQL_File}"
echo SQL_FILE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SQL_FILE="./test.ql"
```

Comment: you can not add any blank space before or after the equal symbol when you declare some variables in shell.

Comment: Hi, this worked, but still encounter the "No such file or directory" on the 4th line.

Comment: line 4 "${SQL_FILE}", not "${SQL_File}"